# How can I switch off the CiviCRM print icon on public pages?

Tags: ui

We set up a petition page, which all works fine.

In order to simplify the user experience, we want to "switch off" the CiviCRM printer icon.

Can this be done using the admin interface?
Or do we need to do some customization? (and what?)

Thanks, 
Detlev

Comment: I am looking for a solution also, especially because the page isn't print friendly.

Answer (score 8):

I think hiding it with CSS might be the most straightforward solution to this... I don't believe this is an option that can be toggled on/off in the admin settings.

Hope this helps,
Lesley